# Как определить лицензии Windows

Tags: windows

У меня есть несколько ключей лицензий windows 10 и компьютеры на которых они стоят, как мне определить какой ключ соответствует какой лицензии на компьютере?

Comment: Не помню откуда у меня этот файл, но он позволяет получить систему (пример: `Windows 8`), её ID и сам ключ. [Ссылка на файл](https://file.io/pSCSAD4LkcJ8)

Comment: @ΝNL993 это сработало на window10, предлагаю написать ответ, чтобы можно было принять. Только не знаю как оформить ссылкой или текст скрипта. И почему тут за вопрос стоит -1?

Comment: *Только не знаю как оформить ссылкой или текст скрипта.* Файл может пропасть с файлопомойки, а текст скрипта останется в ответе - так что выбор очевиден.

Comment: PS. См. https://remontka.pro/windows-10-key/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот скрипт для получения названия, ID и самого ключа системы (Работает с Windows 7 до Windows 10 включительно. На Windows 11 не проверялось):

```vb
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
regKey = "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\"
DigitalProductId = WshShell.RegRead(regKey & "DigitalProductId")
Win8ProductName = "Windows Product Name: " & WshShell.RegRead(regKey & "ProductName") & vbNewLine
Win8ProductID = "Windows Product ID: " & WshShell.RegRead(regKey & "ProductID") & vbNewLine
Win8ProductKey = ConvertToKey(DigitalProductId)
strProductKey ="Windows Key: " & Win8ProductKey
Win8ProductID = Win8ProductName & Win8ProductID & strProductKey ' Соединяем всё в одну строку
MsgBox(Win8ProductKey) ' Отображаем ключ
MsgBox(Win8ProductID) ' Отображаем название, ID и ключ системы
Function ConvertToKey(regKey)
Const KeyOffset = 52
isWin8 = (regKey(66) \ 6) And 1
regKey(66) = (regKey(66) And &HF7) Or ((isWin8 And 2) * 4)
j = 24
Chars = "BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXY2346789"
Do
Cur = 0
y = 14
Do
Cur = Cur * 256
Cur = regKey(y + KeyOffset) + Cur
regKey(y + KeyOffset) = (Cur \ 24)
Cur = Cur Mod 24
y = y -1
Loop While y >= 0
j = j -1
winKeyOutput = Mid(Chars, Cur + 1, 1) & winKeyOutput
Last = Cur
Loop While j >= 0
If (isWin8 = 1) Then
keypart1 = Mid(winKeyOutput, 2, Last)
insert = "N"
winKeyOutput = Replace(winKeyOutput, keypart1, keypart1 & insert, 2, 1, 0)
If Last = 0 Then winKeyOutput = insert & winKeyOutput
End If
a = Mid(winKeyOutput, 1, 5)
b = Mid(winKeyOutput, 6, 5)
c = Mid(winKeyOutput, 11, 5)
d = Mid(winKeyOutput, 16, 5)
e = Mid(winKeyOutput, 21, 5)
ConvertToKey = a & "-" & b & "-" & c & "-" & d & "-" & e

End Function
```

Сохраните данный скрипт в файл, с расширением `.vb`, и запустите его.

Самый близкий скрипт к тому что был у меня, который я смог найти, это в [этом источнике](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/find-windows-10-product-key-using-vb-script).